# installing opencv with homebrew: error 'dispatch_apply_f' was not declared in this scope

Tags: opencv, osx-leopard

I'm trying to install opencv with homebrew on OS 10.5.8 but I'm totally stumped by this error:

```
brew install -v opencv

/tmp/opencv-Qk23/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/parallel.cpp:106:39: error: dispatch/dispatch.h: No such file or directory
/tmp/opencv-Qk23/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/parallel.cpp: In function 'void cv::parallel_for_(const cv::Range&, const cv::ParallelLoopBody&, double)':
/tmp/opencv-Qk23/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/parallel.cpp:267: error: 'dispatch_queue_t' was not declared in this scope
/tmp/opencv-Qk23/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/parallel.cpp:267: error: expected `;' before 'concurrent_queue'
/tmp/opencv-Qk23/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/parallel.cpp:268: error: 'concurrent_queue' was not declared in this scope
/tmp/opencv-Qk23/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/parallel.cpp:268: error: 'dispatch_apply_f' was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/parallel.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should add whether you've tried something to get rid of that error, what instructions are you using, your install environment, and of course, before asking something, google it!

Comment: I got some help from someone else. My macbook is 32 bit, so I needed to install the 32 bit version of opencv using the --with-tbb library to get around call to dispatch_apply_f. The following install worked for me: `option brew install opencv --32-bit -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5 --with-tbb`